# Flutter Firebase RealtimeDatabase info automatically deletes new nodes in error

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat page in my app where a user must agree to my EULA.  I'm trying to save an entry in their user info that lets the app know to no longer ask for the agreement.  I'm logged into Firebase and I can see the info added but then immediately turns red and deletes.  I'm not sure if another of my functions is overwriting my agreement update or not.  Here are my functions and my page init code....

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chatAgreement = null;
    _ensureLoggedIn().whenComplete(() => _getUserInfo());
  }

  Future<void> _getUserInfo() async {
    var userInfo = await fb.child('users/$uid').once();
    print(userInfo.value['chatAgreement']);
    setState(() {
      userName = userInfo.value['displayName'];
      userImage = userInfo.value['image'];
      chatAgreement = userInfo.value['chatAgreement'];
    });
  }

  Future updateAgreement() async {
    String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    fb.child('users/$currentUser').update({
      'chatAgreement': 'agreed',
    });

    setState(() {
      chatAgreement = 'agreed';
    });
  }

Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  uid = user.uid;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use set with merge true  ```.set({...}, SetOptions(merge: true))``` instead of update

Comment: @test: those are options for Firestore, while OP is using Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one write operation in the code you shared, the one that updates the current user to update its `chatAgreement` property. There's no way that code can be overwriting any other properties of the user profile.

But if you are calling `set` somewhere else on the same path/user profile, it may be the case that this call is triggered later than the `update` of the `chatAgreement`.

If that is the cause of the problem, the best path forward is to check why the `set` is happening and fix that problem in your flow. But alternatively, you can also call `update` there instead of `set` so that neither of the write operations gets into each other's way.

And to make this more robust, you may want to [write a security rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/get-started) that [validates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules) that `chatAgreement` can never be deleted/overwritten once it's been set to `agreed`. That's look something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "chatAgreement": {
          ".validate": "data.val() !== 'agreed'"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Frank...  The rules change happend once, but when I logged out and logged in with a new user I got the same issue.  Do you think that this may be do to using this over the emulator?